# How can i make use of 2 lists that will give me a list according to a math formula

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function, math

```
import math

text = ["duran duran sang wild boys in 1984", "wild boys don't reman forever wild", "who brought wild flowers", "it was john krakauer who wrote in to the wild"]
print(text)

def get_unique_words(a):
    visited = set()
    uniq = []
    for b in a.split():
       if b not in visited:
           uniq.append(b)
           visited.add(b)
   return uniq

def get_unique_words_from_list_of_strings(str_list):
    return get_unique_words(' '.join(str_list))

words_in_order = get_unique_words_from_list_of_strings(text)

def countInListOfLists(l, x):
counts = [s.count(x) for s in l]
return sum([1 for c in counts if c > 0])

def dfcounter():
    return [countInListOfLists(text, word) for word in words_in_order]

print(dfcounter())

output1 is ['duran', 'sang', 'wild', 'boys', 'in', '1984', "don't", 'remain', 'forever', 'who', 'brought', 'flowers', 'it', 'was', 'john', 'krakauer', 'wrote', 'to', 'the']
output2 is [1, 1, 4, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

According to these lists i need to match 'duran' with 1 'sang' with 1 'wild' with 4 'boys' with 2 etc.

according to this formula : `math.log(4/(number matched with the string goes here), 10)` (ex: math.log(4/1, 10) equals 0.602)

how do i repeat this code unlike this:

```
[math.log(4/1, 10), math.log(4/1, 10), math.log(4/4, 10)]
```

so it will repeat for every word in output 1

and final output will be this for example :

```
[0.602, 0.602, 0.0, 0.301, 0.301, 0.602, 0.602, 0.602, 0.602, 0.301, 0.602, 0.602, 0.602, 0.602, 0.602, 0.602, 0.602, 0.602, 0.602]
```

if you need further clarification please tell me

Comment: You have questionable implementations: Why `" ".join` just to `.split` it right after. Also, counting unique elements can be done simpler with a set comprehension.

Comment: i didnt write my whole code i needed to do that for the other part of my code(it works when i do that i really dont know why) sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple list comprehension.

```
import math
mylist = [1, 1, 4, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
print([math.log(4.0/x, 10) for x in mylist])
```

Output:

```
[0.6020599913279623, 0.6020599913279623, 0.0, 0.30102999566398114, 0.30102999566398114, 0.6020599913279623, 0.6020599913279623, 0.6020599913279623, 0.6020599913279623, 0.30102999566398114, 0.6020599913279623, 0.6020599913279623, 0.6020599913279623, 0.6020599913279623, 0.6020599913279623, 0.6020599913279623, 0.6020599913279623, 0.6020599913279623, 0.6020599913279623]
```

List (and dict) comprehensions are awesome :-)

Comment: i cant believe i wrote all that just to not notice something so simple thanks a bunch my friend !